# ¿Cómo mejorar el rendimiento en SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

He estado buscando algo de información pero encontrado algo referente al tema. Por ejemplo quisiera saber que es mejor hacer:

```
WHILE <condicion> BEGIN
  update Tabla1 set Fecha1 = @Fecha1 where id=@id
  update Tabla1 set Fecha2 = @Fecha2 where id=@id
  update Tabla1 set Fecha2 = @Fecha2 where id=@id
END
```

ó

```
WHILE <condicion> BEGIN
  update Tabla1 set Fecha1 = @Fecha1, Fecha2 = @Fecha2, Fecha2 = @Fecha2 
where id=@id
```

La duda es, es mejor hacerlo en una linea o no importa? Es que tengo una tabla de unos 60,000 registros que se tarda como 2:30hrs en hacer este tipo de operaciones, es normal?.

Este es el código de donde surgió la pregunta (Ojala ayude a resolver mi duda):

```
WHILE @RowNum > 0 
BEGIN 
    set @Numero_Contrato = null
    set @Plazo = 0
    set @NumPago = 0
    set @MaxPag = 0
    set @NumPagoPaso = 0
    set @MaxPagPaso = 0
    set @BandPagoDespues =0
    set @ContratoBase = null

    select @Numero_Contrato = convert(int,Key_Busqueda) from TIntereses15 where ID_Key = @MyCont
    select @MaxPag = MAX(Num_Pago) from TablaAmortizacion where ID_FolPrestamo = @Numero_Contrato

    select @NumPago = Num_Pago from TablaAmortizacion where Fecha_PagoPensiones = (select MAX(Fecha_PagoPensiones) 
        from TablaAmortizacion where ID_FolPrestamo = @Numero_Contrato) 
        and ID_FolPrestamo = @Numero_Contrato

    if(@NumPago is null or (@NumPago = 0 and @MaxPag = 0)) --Caso de folios que nacen en este mes pero se pagaran hasta el siguiente en (fechaPagoPensiones)
    begin
        select @NumPago = Num_Pago from TablaAmortizacion where Fecha_Pago = (select Min(Fecha_Pago) 
            from TablaAmortizacion where ID_FolPrestamo = @Numero_Contrato)
            and ID_FolPrestamo = @Numero_Contrato
    end
    else
        set @NumPago = @NumPago
    if(@NumPago is null)
    begin
        select @NumPago = Num_Pago from TablaAmortizacion where Year(Fecha_Pago) in (@Anio) and Month(Fecha_Pago) in (@Periodo + 1)
        and ID_FolPrestamo = @Numero_Contrato
    end
    select @interes = Sum(InteresPagarCifrasControl) from CarteraDetalle where Numero_Contrato = @Numero_Contrato
    if (@interes is null)
        select @interes = Sum(InteresPagarCifrasControl) from CarteraDetalle where ContratoKey = @Numero_Contrato
    update TIntereses15 set Interes = @interes where ID_Key = @MyCont
    update TIntereses15 set Interes_ContravalDivisaLocal =replace('+' + REPLICATE('0', 18 - LEN(Rtrim(Ltrim(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@interes)))))
        + Rtrim(Ltrim(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@interes))),'.',',')
    where ID_Key = @MyCont
    set @RowNum = @RowNum - 1
    set @MyCont = @MyCont + 1
END
```

Comment: por que es necesario el ciclo?

Comment: 60000 registros, 2 horas y media no es normal ni para access.. aca hay otro problema claramente.

Comment: 60000 registros es un excel de los viejos.. y ni ahi tardarias tanto

Comment: Son dos tablas una de cuentas y la otra de las amortizaciones de estás, la lógica es; de la tabla de cuentas sacar el no. de cuenta buscarlo en la de amortizaciones y sumar el interés de esa tabla  y también sumar este total de todas las cuentas.

Comment: Siempre sera mejor la segunda opcion, ya que en una misma linea hace una sola consulta con la otra harias tres consultas iguales para actualizar un solo elemento. Ahora el problema de la tardanza puede que sea un problema en la indexacion de las tablas.